# Strange NVME Drive Behaviour with Arch/Windows 11 Dual Boot

Tags: boot, uefi, arch-linux, windows-11, nvme

I've got two nvme drives in my system, one with Arch on it, and the other with Win11 on it. Both operating systems share an EFI partition on the Arch drive.

I've noticed that the Windows drive intermittently seems to vanish from my system when I reboot. It's not visible in the UEFI, it's not visible within Linux, it's just... Gone. If I try to boot Windows, it complains about it not being able to find the OS files.

I don't think the drive is dead, as if I pull the battery out of my laptop, it miraculously appears again, I've checked the SMART report for it when it's up and I can't see any issues in there.

Honestly, I'm totally stumped, where would I even start with debugging this?

```
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.0.11-arch1-g14-1] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Sabrent Rocket 4.0 1TB
Serial Number:                      054607081CF388182843
Firmware Version:                   RKT401.3
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1987
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x6479a7
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      1
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            6479a7 3ca0204fb2
Local Time is:                      Sun Dec 11 17:43:51 2022 GMT
Firmware Updates (0x12):            1 Slot, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005d):     Comp DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x08):         Telmtry_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     90 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     95 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     9.78W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.75W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     5.23W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0490W       -        -    3  3  3  3     2000    2000
 4 -   0.0018W       -        -    4  4  4  4    25000   25000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         2
 1 -    4096       0         1

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        53 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          5%
Percentage Used:                    4%
Data Units Read:                    37,429,775 [19.1 TB]
Data Units Written:                 32,154,799 [16.4 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 252,303,210
Host Write Commands:                240,664,409
Controller Busy Time:               413
Power Cycles:                       44,086
Power On Hours:                     5,485
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   463
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      1,321
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 63 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0       1321     0  0x0000  0x4004  0x028            0     0     -
```

Comment: Sounds like firmware bug to me. See if there's an update from the vendor?

Comment: The laptop is a GA503QS, as far as I can see, everything is up to date, I'm running the latest BIOS v413, unless there's another firmware package that can be flashed that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I never understand why people mention SMART was looked at but not include it.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - I didn't include it because everything looked reasonably healthy... But give me a sec and I'll add it to the post

Comment: @JoepvanSteen - There you go

Comment: Have you taken the drive out and put it back, in case it isn't seated quite right?

Comment: And does the [Sabrent Control Panel](https://sabrent.com/collections/internal-memory/products/sb-rocket-nvme4-1tb) indicate that there are any firmware updates available for the drive?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes to your first comment, and it indicates the fw is up to date on your second

Comment: The SMART attributes look like nonsense - there are no values, just N/A, so the OK status is weird. I think the disk is having issues.

Comment: @harrymc The raw values make perfect sense. It's an NVNe drive btw.

Comment: @harrymc - The drive is fine, I'm pretty confident of that one

Comment: @TomYan: I too have an NVMe drive and it has all the SMART data, not only raw values. It might be a problem with the disk, or with the DiskCheckup app. Also, a disk's disappearing is usually a sign of trouble.

Comment: That `Power cycle count` is ludicrously high at `44086` with `5481` `power on time`. That suggests over 228 days, you have rebooted it an average of `8` times per hour. This does assume that POT is in hours. Boot into Linux and see what `smartctl -x <dev>` gives you. It may be that `DiskCheckup` does not fully know about the device, and probably not `smartctl` either.

Comment: @Bib - I've replaced the smart details with the output from smartctl, I wonder if the number of power cycles could be due to linux/the controller cycling it trying to get it to start up when it's in whatever faulty state it's in?

Comment: So I've disabled fast startup and sleep in Windows... Since then, I've not been able to replicate the issue so it *might* be solved. But it was always a temperamental issues so I can't be too sure just yet. Does Windows do some weird stuff with drive states when using either of those features that might be the cause?

Comment: Further to my last... The issue just recurred, so that wasn't the fix I thought it might be